# Group by and Aggregate dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to group by a certain column and take the aggregates of other columns.

df

```
version     host    date        name    purpose date
pat         A       12/1/2019   pat     hi      12/1/2019
fam         A       12/1/2019   fam     cat     12/1/2019
set         BB      12/2/2019   set     hi      12/2/2020
ok          BB      12/2/2019   ok      hi      12/2/2020
sure        BB      12/2/2019   sure    cat     12/2/2020
```

DESIRED

```
version host    date        name    purpose date    
2       A       12/1/2019   2       2       12/1/2019   
3       B       12/2/2019   3       3       12/2/2019
```

DOING

```
df.groupby['host].agg({'version' : 'count', 'name': 'count' , 'purpose': 'count'})
```

However, this is not giving me the count of the desired columns. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this?

```
>>> df.groupby('host').agg({'version' : 'count', 'name': 'count' , 'purpose': 'count', 'date': 'first'})
      version  name  purpose       date
host
A           2     2        2  12/1/2019
BB          3     3        3  12/2/2019
```

Comment: Thank you. does the first attribute just take the first row?

Comment: Yep, exactly that. You can also use `last` (